# Yii2 formatter show different date

Tags: yii2

I want to view time from db and then save it to another db.table in timestamp format, but I've get different time every time I convert it:

```
        print_r($sub_datetime['datetime']);echo "<br>";
        $temptime = Yii::$app->formatter->asTimestamp($sub_datetime['datetime']);
        print_r($temptime);echo "<br> ";
        $temptime2 = Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime($temptime);
        print_r($temptime2);echo "<br> ";
        $temptime3 = Yii::$app->formatter->asTimestamp($temptime2);
        print_r($temptime3);echo "<br> ";
```

Get:

```
10-5-2015 10:00
1431252000
10-5-2015 13:00
1431262800
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Issue

**asTimestamp** function assumes that the date you have specified is UTC by default and gives out the UTC time value.

**asDatetime** function however thinks otherwise and gets the system timezone, giving you back the date with the system timezone offset.

### Solution

You have a few options, any one will work

1. Set the yii formatter timezone to utc `Yii::$app->formatter->timeZone = 'UTC';` before calling `asDatetime` function (and set back to original if needed).
2. Before passing the timestamp to **asTimestamp**, offset it by your timezone to convert it to UTC.
3. After getting the result of asDatetime, offset it by timezone in order to convert it back to UTC