# Yii2 formatter asDate return different day

Tags: php, date, yii2, formatter

I have 2 servers with the same project code but i get different output day from the yii formatter on the production server and i have no clue what configuration could cause this difference...

it's different from the topic discussed here [Yii2 formater show different date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052237/yii2-formater-show-different-date) because i think its not a timezone/hour difference, instead its outputs always **1 day before** the correct date.

in controller i have get a model data from mysql column that is a datetime.
then i log different formatter strings but always same different date obtained, *1 day before*.

```
\Yii::trace('fechaEntrega in BD: '.$model->fechaEntrega);
$fmt = 'php:d-m-Y';
\Yii::trace('fechaEntrega formatter as date: '.$fmt.': '.\Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->fechaEntrega, $fmt));
$fmt = 'd-M-Y';
\Yii::trace('fechaEntrega formatter as date: '.$fmt.': '.\Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->fechaEntrega, $fmt));
$fmt = 'php:Y-m-d';
\Yii::trace('fechaEntrega formatter as date: '.$fmt.': '.\Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->fechaEntrega, $fmt));
$formatter = \Yii::$app->formatter;
\Yii::trace('Formatter config: '.\yii\helpers\VarDumper::dumpAsString(\Yii::$app->formatter));
```

I get the follow output from production server:

```
fechaEntrega in BD: 2016-08-23 00:00:00
fechaEntrega formatter as date: php:d-m-Y: 22-08-2016
fechaEntrega formatter as date: d-M-Y: 22-8-2016
fechaEntrega formatter as date: php:Y-m-d: 2016-08-22

Formatter config: yii\i18n\Formatter#1 ( 
    [nullDisplay] => '<span class=\"not-set\">(no definido)</span>'
    [booleanFormat] => [ 0 => 'No' 1 => 'Sí' ]
    [locale] => 'es-CL' 
    [timeZone] => 'America/Santiago' 
    [defaultTimeZone] => 'America/Santiago' 
    [dateFormat] => 'php:d-m-Y' 
    [timeFormat] => 'medium' 
    [datetimeFormat] => 'medium' 
    [calendar] => null 
    [decimalSeparator] => null 
    [thousandSeparator] => null 
    [numberFormatterOptions] => [] 
    [numberFormatterTextOptions] => [] 
    [numberFormatterSymbols] => [] 
    [currencyCode] => null
    [sizeFormatBase] => 1024
    [yii\i18n\Formatter:_intlLoaded] => true 
    [yii\i18n\Formatter:_dateFormats] => [ 'short' => 3 'medium' => 2 'long' => 1 'full' => 0 ] 
    [yii\base\Component:_events] => [] 
    [yii\base\Component:_behaviors] => null 
)
```

The test server works fine, it formats right the datetimes... only production server have this difference and yii config its the same

the one differencebetween the 2 servers, but i dont think it could cause the issue, its the RTC time when i get the timedatectl command:

in Test server:

```
$ timedatectl 
Local time: mié 2016-08-17 10:03:29 CLST
Universal time: mié 2016-08-17 13:03:29 UTC
RTC time: mié 2016-08-17 09:04:02
Time zone: America/Santiago (CLST, -0300)
Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: no
RTC in local TZ: yes

$ date
mié ago 17 10:07:29 CLST 2016
```

And in Production Server:

```
# timedatectl 
Local time: Wed 2016-08-17 10:03:16 CLST
Universal time: Wed 2016-08-17 13:03:16 UTC
RTC time: Wed 2016-08-17 13:03:16
Timezone: America/Santiago (CLST, -0300)
NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: no
RTC in local TZ: no
DST active: yes
Last DST change: DST began at
     Sat 2016-08-13 23:59:59 CLT
     Sun 2016-08-14 01:00:00 CLST
Next DST change: DST ends (the clock jumps one hour backwards) at
     Sat 2017-05-13 23:59:59 CLST
     Sat 2017-05-13 23:00:00 CLT

# date
Wed Aug 17 10:07:18 CLST 2016
```

Also i have the Intl extension enabled as the Yii Formatter documentation says http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-formatting.html#localizing-data-format

Comment: What happens on both servers when `$model->fechaEntrega` is more than 3 hours from `2016-08-23 00:00:00` - for example `2016-08-23 04:00:00`?

Comment: I use only the date part, the time is set to 00:00:00

Comment: y printed the time to check and Bizley you are on the right track!
fechaEntrega formatter as date: php:d-m-Y H:i:s: 22-08-2016 23:00:00
its converts to 1 hour before, so it change the day....
it probably is a timezone issue because here in Chile we have GMT-4 and GMT-3 and somewhere must be messed out, but where??

Comment: There is difference between servers RTC. Try to set `'timeZone' => 'America/Santiago'` in your config for the whole app as well (on main level, not just in formatter component) and let me know if this does anything.

Comment: i already had set timeZone to 'America/Santiago' in app config
the difference is 1 hour earlier when use formatter...

it seems that somewhere its getting  'America/Santiago' to GMT-4 instead of GMT-3??

Comment: @Bizley i give up... 
i Set app timeZone and formatter timeZone, defaultTimeZone to 'UTC' and its working fine....
in some days i will try again to see whats failing..... but for know i give up
Thanks for your Help!!

Comment: No problem. I find it easier to keep all dates as unix timestamps - this way there are no problems with formatter.